# Share photo albums via obfuscated urls, without requiring user-accounts

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm looking to create a "local" photo sharing application with Meteor, which allows visitors to either create a sort of private lobby, or post photos to a private lobby (allowing for local slideshows, for example).

To do this, I would need to be able to generate some kind of unique password or code, which people could use to gain access to the local slideshow and then be able to add pictures to it.

Can anyone give me pointers on this? Or Meteor resources I can take a look at in terms of setting up "private lobbies" of this sort, accessible only by a generated key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a collection called "Lobbies"
2. Add documents to that collection, each will have a random id automatically
3. Create a route (using *FlowRouter* or *iron-router*) that loads that lobby document and all related photographs, ex: `/:lobbyId`
4. Don't publish these lobbies unless they are requested specifically by `_id`, this will prevent them from being accidentally discovered

Now your users can add pictures to lobbies and exchange the urls of these lobbies and only the people who know the url will gain access.

Comment: Very cool, thanks for that! Do you mind if I ask why use FlowRouter instead of iron-router?

Comment: There are many articles on this, ex: https://themeteorchef.com/blog/the-state-of-routing-in-meteor/ Everyone pretty much agrees f-r is the future and i-r is the past. This will be true until the next hot router arrives on the scene. Pro tip: don't marry your router, just date it.